# Nhibernate mapping generator create mapping files without Schema()

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I use this generator - http://nmg.codeplex.com/. But it generates mapping files without schema. I have to go through all mapping files and manually insert `Schema("someschema")` method. How can I generate entities and mapping files with schema? Maybe another generator? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

there is the NH.Cfg.Environment.DefaultSchema property which can be set on the NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration and there are also FNH's Conventions to set the Schema for each class see `IClassConvention`.